# Is there any "READPAST" in Entity framework 5?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Is there a way to use/issue the SQL Server READPAST table hint in an entity framework LINQ query?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Please don't use Stack Overflow as your personal search engine.

Comment: I couldnt find the answer in msdn nor google then i tried here. thats why iam asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF has no support for table hints. If you need to write a query with table hint you must either use SQL directly or map a stored procedure / table valued function using such query.